# Корень из 2 в степени корень из 2 в степени корень из 2

Tags: математика, рекурсия, уравнения

Есть число, которое можно представить так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решаю его так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но тогда подходят 2 корня: 2 и 4.

Единственное место, где, как мне кажется, мог ошибиться это переход между первой и второй строчкой решения. Но вроде же нормальный рекурсивный переход. Что в этом решение не так?

Comment: Решаете ... что? Где условие?

Comment: @MBo нужно найти чему равно число, которое записывается так, как указано

Comment: В предпоследней строчке у вас перепутаны справа местами члены уравнения. Посмотрите на строчку до неё и после неё, там всё правильно.

Comment: @CrazyElf да, спасибо, поправил

Comment: Все такие действия разрешены только при абсолютно сходящемся ряде, а при x == 4 ряд расходится... Вроде бы так (но не очень уверен, что именно тут рассматривать как сходимость - несходимость)...

Comment: @Harry ниже уже доказали, что сходится

Comment: К 4? Или к 2? Строгого математического доказательства, кстати (через какие-нибудь критерии Коши и т.п.) я не увидел, не более чем сходимость *итерационного процесса*, и то на пальцах...

Comment: @Harry я не стал всю выкладку прикладывать, это муторно. Но там базовый анализ функции ln(x)/x, в результате 1 точка экстремума и тд и тп и в результате 2 корня, а дальше методом подбора, что это корни 2 и 4.

Comment: Это не доказательство сходимости ряда `x_i = sqrt(2)^sqrt(2)^sqrt(2)^..i_раз..^sqrt(2)`

Comment: @Harry а я про ряд ничего в своих рассуждениях и не говорил.

Comment: Еще раз и медленно, как для милиционера. Ваши выкладки совершенно справедливы, если ряд сходится. Для расходящегося ряда можно такими выкладками доказать что угодно, понимаете? Даже что сумма положительных членов отрицательна... Вот как доказать — вопрос второй, тут я пока не вижу, как это сделать...

Comment: @Harry как вы угадали кем я работаю =D Только попрошу правильно: полицейский

Comment: Посмотрите вот эту ссылку: https://socratic.org/questions/is-sqrt-2-sqrt-2-rational-and-sqrt-2-sqrt-2-sqrt-2 Там четко показано, что это ряд возрастающий и ограничен сверху значением 2. Вот вам и ответ — корень 4 не годится.

Comment: @Harry пока это мне понятней всего. Спасибо за ссылку!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Итак, рассмотрим ряд

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

с k возведениями в степень. Тогда

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь по индукции докажем, что последовательность возрастающая и ограничена сверху 2. Базу индукции мы только что записали.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот теперь, когда мы **доказали**, что ряд возрастающий и ограничен сверху, т.е. **сходится**, мы применяем ваш метод (имеем право!).

И находим, что корень 4 не годится, так как ряд ограничен сверху двойкой.

Значит, остается единственное решение — 2.

Оригинал [тут](https://socratic.org/questions/is-sqrt-2-sqrt-2-rational-and-sqrt-2-sqrt-2-sqrt-2).

Answer (score 0):

возможно у вас вот такой пример был:

```
x^x^x^x^.... = 2
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrOG1tKAatg

т.е. в вашем решении надо

1. найти корни
2. проверить корни

тогда корень `4` отпадёт, вернее получается `x^4 = 4 => x = sqrt(2)` и опять приходим к тому, что такая степенная башня равна `2`

Comment: Это сходящаяся последовательность. Возьмите `x_0 = sqrt(2)`, `x_{i+1} = sqrt(2)**x_i` . Сходимость на глаз линейная, примерно четыре итерации на знак.

Comment: вы правы, я просто задачу видел в другом виде (привел ее в скорректированном ответе)

Comment: Но если взять x^x^x^x^... = 4 то результат тоже будет x = sqrt(2)

Или я что-то не понял в вашей логике

Answer (score 0):

Если честно, я не вижу причину для волнения.

С одной стороны, итерационный процесс `x_{i+1} = ln(x_i)*2/ln(2)` имеет две неподвижные точки: 2 и 4.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но вы же ведёте итерацию не абы как, а начинаете её в точке `x_0 = sqrt(2)`. Из этой точки итерация сходится к `x = 2`.

Кстати, к `x = 4` никакая итерация сойтись не сможет, это неустойчивая неподвижная точка. Шаг влево - итерация сходится к 2. Шаг вправо - итерация уходит на бесконечность.

Comment: Т.е. в итоге нельзя сказать чему равно или как упростить исходное представление числа?

Comment: @АлексейДанчин разумеется сказать можно. Это число равно 2. Итерационный процесс, начатый в `x_0 = sqrt(2)`, сходится к устойчивой неподвижной точке.